# multiple image upload in firebase (android studio)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I wanna make an application that can upload more than 1 photos and save the imgUrl in firebase database and in firebase storage. But until now, I have not found reference that meets my needs. I need your help. Thanks so much.

I've tried an example, but it still not success when upload the url to firebase database and firebase storage

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private static Button openCustomGallery, btnUploadImage;
private static GridView selectedImageGridView;

private static final int CustomGallerySelectId = 1;//Set Intent Id
public static final String CustomGalleryIntentKey = "ImageArray";//Set Intent Key Value

private StorageReference storageReference;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
    setListeners();
    getSharedImages();
    btnUploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            upload();
        }
    });
}

//Init all views
private void initViews() {
    openCustomGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openCustomGallery);
    selectedImageGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImagesGridView);
    btnUploadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUploadGambar);
}

//set Listeners
private void setListeners() {
    openCustomGallery.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.openCustomGallery:
            //Start Custom Gallery Activity by passing intent id
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomGallery_Activity.class), CustomGallerySelectId);
            break;
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode,
                                Intent imagereturnintent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, imagereturnintent);
    switch (requestcode) {
        case CustomGallerySelectId:
            if (resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
                String imagesArray = imagereturnintent.getStringExtra(CustomGalleryIntentKey);//get Intent data
                //Convert string array into List by splitting by ',' and substring after '[' and before ']'
                List<String> selectedImages = Arrays.asList(imagesArray.substring(1, imagesArray.length() - 1).split(", "));
                loadGridView(new ArrayList<String>(selectedImages));//call load gridview method by passing converted list into arrayList
            }
            break;

    }
}

//Load GridView
private void loadGridView(ArrayList<String> imagesArray) {
    GridView_Adapter adapter = new GridView_Adapter(MainActivity.this, imagesArray, false);
    selectedImageGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//Read Shared Images
private void getSharedImages() {

    //If Intent Action equals then proceed
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(getIntent().getAction())
            && getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
        ArrayList<Parcelable> list =
                getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);//get Parcelabe list
        ArrayList<String> selectedImages = new ArrayList<>();

        //Loop to all parcelable list
        for (Parcelable parcel : list) {
            Uri uri = (Uri) parcel;//get URI
            String sourcepath = getPath(uri);//Get Path of URI
            selectedImages.add(sourcepath);//add images to arraylist
        }
        loadGridView(selectedImages);//call load gridview
    }
}


//get actual path of uri
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

private void upload() {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    StorageReference sRef = storageReference.child(projection);
    sRef.putFile(projection).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Upload upload = new Upload(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
            String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
            mDatabase.child(id).setValue(upload);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Upload.java

```
public class Upload {
public String<Uri> images = new ArrayList<>();

public Upload(List<Uri> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

public List<Uri> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<Uri> images) {
    this.images = images;
}
```

Comment: What platform are you using? Have you read firebase documentation on how to implement these things? And have you done any research? If you do pls include in the post. One can't help other without enough information.

Comment: yes, i've edited my post. im using android studio @UmarZaii